# I have one variable but Java considers them as two

Tags: java, variables, colors

I have initiated the variable 'answer' in the near header of the class.
Later on when, a random number within an entered range has been generated, that same variable gets a new different value (due to the random generator). But as you can see, the variable 'answer' is indicated in two different colors (blue vs light brown), and as you expect, the routines that I have made are therefore not working. Somehow answer is not equal to answer. What did I do wrongly???? (unfortunately here you don't see the difference in colors).

- In eclipse the color of 'answer' at the very top `static int answer = 0;` is BLUE.
- But the one `int answer = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, userinput);` is GREY

Here's my code:

```java
package Package1;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class test6KOPIE

{

    static int numberofattempts = 0;
    static int maxnummerofattemptsallowed = 5;
    static int answer = 0;


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {



            if (answer == 0)
            {


                Scanner maxinput = new Scanner(System.in);


                System.out.println("Under which number do you want to guess");


                int userinput = maxinput.nextInt();

                int answer = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, userinput);


                System.out.println(answer);

                main(args);                     
            }

            else if (numberofattempts < maxnummerofattemptsallowed)
               {


                    Scanner higherlower = new Scanner(System.in);

                    System.out.println("Higher or Lower");

                    int digit = higherlower.nextInt();


                    if  (answer == digit)
                        {
                        System.out.println("very well");
                        }

                    else    {
                            if (answer > digit ) 
                                {
                                ++numberofattempts;
                                System.out.println("Higher, you have " +(maxnummerofattemptsallowed - numberofattempts)+" attempt(s) left)");
                                System.out.println(numberofattempts);
                                main(args);
                                }

                            else
                                {
                                ++numberofattempts;
                                System.out.println("Lower, you have " +(maxnummerofattemptsallowed - numberofattempts)+" attempt(s) left)");
                                main(args);
                                }

                            }


                    higherlower.close();    
               }

                else    {
                        System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts used, the answer was" +answer);
                        }


        }
```

Comment: It seems this time stackoverflow doesn't show the code in color. Very weird

Comment: Edited. You need to select the code and press {} to make it recognized as code (and be shifted right by 4 spaces)

Comment: it seems it recognized what the code is, but still no coloration.

Comment: it seems my own edit didn't go thru. But if you add java after the first 3 ''' as '''java, on my computer the color works

Comment: I also had tagged your question as java, you should add that to get more answers!

Comment: Thanks the coloring works. But I thought I gave two tags with it. Namely, Variables and colors. Or do you means something else?

Comment: I tried again to add the 'java' tag, it should be being processed... It's more needed than the other 2, as that's what will get java experts to see your question!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are re-initializing your `answer` variable by retyping `int` before it. If you simply want to reassign the value, the line should be:

`answer=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, userinput);`

Comment: As a note, this would likely not change the functionality of your code.